# Проблема при POST запросе с помощью Angular к SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, angular

Проблема возникает при пост запросе. В теле запроса несколько временных отметок, все, кроме одной, корректно принимаются Rest сервисом на Spring Boot.
Проблемную временную отметку отличает то, что поле берется не за счет набора пользователем данных в поле ввода, а присваивается из системного времени. При наборе данных вручную в проблемном поле запрос проходит корректно.

```
 todayDate: Date = new Date(Date.now()); // вызываю время и дату    
    this.callForm.patchValue({
            date: [formatDate(this.todayDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",'en' )], // присваиваю полю значение даты
            time: [formatDate(this.todayDate,"HH:mm",'en' )] // // присваиваю полю значение времени
          })
```

Вызываю значение поля формы:

```
 this.calls.time = this.callForm.get('time').value ; // присваивание полю класса значение формы
```

В spring boot код описания поля идентичен другим временным, исправным полям.
Ошибка:

```
2020-08-18 12:06:25.443  WARN 5340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 22] (through reference chain: com.kiryushin.pspmonitoring.entity.Calls["time"])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с присваиванием значения полю "time" (formControl). Нужно убрать скобки "[" и "]" у "formatDate".

```
  this.callForm.patchValue({
    date: formatDate(this.todayDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",'en' ),
    time: formatDate(this.todayDate,"HH:mm",'en' )
  })
```